# Why do bridges collapse?

Tags: bridge

I'd like to ask if anybody knows why all bridges suddenly go offline at random times? 
It can be viewed via the Tor metrics chart which shows how number of active bridges often hits zero and then comes back.

[image: Relay between dec 2017 and Mar 2018]

[image: Relays between Dec 2017 and Jan 2018]

[image: Relays between Jan 2017 and Jan 2018]

Comment: Does anybody have a suggestion as to why this is happening?

Comment: Metrics glitches, I'd guess.

Comment: If it was a glitch with Tor metrics then wouldn't they have fixed it after the first outage? Very suspicious

Answer (score 1):

Tor Metrics uses a backend server to collect the data from different sources. From time to time this server becomes unreachable, crashes etc. So it doesn't collect data for a short amount of time. You can see the result of it in the diagramm above. Usually it is nothing to worry about. Also the bridges are online the whole time. So if you are a bridge user, you can use it like any other day.